# Are new records added into Hive table (ORC format) appended into the last stripe or a brand new stripe?

Tags: hive, orc

Let's say if I created a hive table as ORC format and inserted 1M records into the table, which created a file with 17 stripes. The last stripe is not full.

Then I insterted another 100 records into this table, will the new 100 records be appended into the last stripe or a new stripe will be created ?

I have tried to test it on a HDFS cluster, seems like every time we insert new records, a new file will be created (of course, new stripes are created too). Was wondering why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason would be HDFS doesn't support editing file.

So `when we insert data` into Hive table all the time new files will be created.

In case if you want to [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042225/how-do-i-combine-or-merge-small-orc-files-into-larger-orc-file) these files you can use [concatenate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate)

```
Alter table <table_name> CONCATENATE;
```

(or)

You can insert overwrite the same table that you have selected from to merge all small files into big file.

```
insert overwrite <db_table>.<table1> select * from <db_table>.<table1>
```

You can also use [sort by distribute by](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ORC-Creation-Best-Practices/ta-p/248963) to control number of files created in HDFS directory.

Comment: thanks @Shu, that's very clear and helps a lot for me.